# Safari CSS transition jumping with transform(x,y)

Tags: css, safari, transform, transition

[see here the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXfgs.gif)
I`m trying to create a css transition from:

```
.menu{
 transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
 // transform: translate(-50%, -50%); also not working properly
 transform 0.75s 0s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
}
```

to

```
.menu.pinned{
 transform: translate3d(-50%, 0%, 0);
 // transform: translate(-50%, 0%); also not working properly
}
```

Menu is moving up and down on y-axis, but jumping on safari (v.12.0) at start and end of the transition. Do someone have an idea why?